# Send WiFi SSID & Pass Phrase to pi3

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am looking into ways to send WiFi SSID and pass phrase to a group of raspberry devices from a mobile app. More specifically:
- The raspberries would switch on in an environment with potentially multiple available WiFi networks.
- From an app, the user would select one of these WiFis and provide the pass phrase
- raspberries would receive the information and connect to the WiFi

One approach would be to make the raspberries to form a WiFi network with one machine acting as access point. The problem with this method is as far as I can tell there is no way an IOS app can use public apple interfaces to connect to a specific WIFI in code - in this case the one run by raspberry.

I have recently bought a Google Chromecast and used its iOS app to easily send SSID and pass phrase of my WiFi to it. I guess I am looking for a similar method.

Thanks

Comment: How about using Bluetooth? Both iPhone and Raspberry Pi 3 have that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that most of the heavy lifting (copying SSID/passphrase to be sent to the devices) would be done by the application.

When it comes to the devices (RPi's) you need to write a custom script in bash or python (or any other language for that matter) that'd be executed by crontab/systemd when devices are started. Then depending on the amount of the devices, you'd need to set a master that'd create a public WiFi network so others can connect to it through WiFi SSID polling.

This way you have a network of Raspberry Pi's ready to accept the requests from any device on the network (your iPhone for example).

To actually get them to accept the data and reconnect to a valid network you'll need to set up a server - either using node.js/tornado/flask that listens on a specific port (to which your app will send the data) and if successfully authenticated (assuming you want authentication) it executes a function that disconnects from their current WiFi network and connects to the new one specified by you. I'd also encourage to get them to look back for the master and reconnect to the old network in case they cannot connect to the one that you asked them to.

You could use other methods like bluetooh or NFC to push the data across as well.

EDIT: When it comes to your phone automatically connecting to the Pi network I guess the easiest way would be to ask the user to manually change the network. I don't own an iPhone or never developed for one so won't be able to help you with that, sorry.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but the user still needs to manually switch the WiFi network before working with the app  to send information to raspberries.